# how to convert list<enum> to string. I need save string in database not number(enum) in C#

Tags: c#, json

**its my enum**

```
public enum Employee_roles
{
    admin,
    controller,
    planner,
    stockkeeper,
    client,
    bpengineer,
    superintendent,
    seniorengineer,
    procurementmanager,
    hseadmin,
    hseclient,
    rawadmin,
}
```

this model class

```
public class access_right
{

    public string id { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public method method { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public List<Employee_roles> roles { get; set; }
    public List<string> email { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public access_type access { get; set; }

}
```

**roles property is List. if it's not list no problem [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] this method working. But List how to convert please help me **

Comment: You can get enums string values using `[Flags]` attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Employee_roles)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save for example your roles as strings, you can use the JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType property like so:

```
[JsonProperty (ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public List<Employee_roles> roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks very helpful thank you sir